# CSSTransition not showing transitions in React

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, react-transition-group

Here's my slideshow.jsx file.I am trying to apply transition to a sample div containing

Sample Text

,but no transitions happening.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';<br>
import styles from '../stylesheets/style.module.css';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
class SlideShow extends Component {

 state = {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    changePic: true,
    slideIndex: 1,
  };

render() {
 console.log(this.state.changePic);
   return (
      <div className={styles.slideshowContainer}>
        <CSSTransition
          in={this.state.changePic}
          timeout={2000}
          classNames={styles.slidePics}
          mountOnEnter={true}
        >
          <div>
            <p>sample text</p>
          </div>
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SlideShow;
```

Here is my style.module.css file.Following properties associated with slidePics are below.But these transitions are not working:-

```
.slidePics-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.slidePics-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2000ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is you dont have a class `slidePics` at your css modules to be mapped to styles. if you add an empty rule `.slidePics { }` solves the issue.

other viable approach, you could map your transictions as:

```
classNames={{
 enter: styles['slidePics-enter'],
 enterActive: styles['slidePics-enter-active'],
}}
```

**update**

you already have `in` prop as true, given initial state. `in` initial state needs to be false and then with some iteraction you would change to true with the classes `enter` `enter-active`.

by your code, you would like to perform transition on mount state but as the [docs](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-prop-appear) says css transition wont perform enter transition by default on first mount.

for that to happen, you need to pass `appear={true}` and `in={true}`. likewise create the classes `.slidePics-appear` `.slidePics-appear-active` like you have for `enter` classes.

Comment: The classNames in react-transition-group correspond to their prefix in the .css file, however we cannot use -(hyphen)  in the .jsx file for referring to .css classnames.

Comment: indeed forgot about it. I updated my answer. you would need to use brackets for that case, or change you css classNames for camelCase.

Comment: i  had tested both options in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/transiction-css-module-mi767?file=/src/App.js), and both options work. hope it helps you out.

Comment: well, code is now syntactically correct, but no transitions yet.

Comment: added aditional info to the post, I believe it solves the remaining issue. regards